# Using a variable as an array parameter in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to use a variable as the index parameter in an array but for some reason it's coming up as "undefined" when I do it this way. Any ideas?

```
var object_number = [];
var x = 1;

    function create_new_object()
    {
        object_number[x] = new happy_object();
        x++;

    }
```

Comment: Did you actually call `create_new_object()`?

Comment: are you accessing `object_number[0]` ? because you are setting `x=1` so index 0 will be undefined if you are trying to access it.

Comment: Do you actually define `happy_object`? (Seriously, this reduced test case has been reduced too far to possibly work, it doesn't even have a line of code that could have anything come up as 'undefined')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array indices start at zero in JavaScript. When `x` starts at `1`, there's an `undefined` element in the first position of the array. Start at `x=0` instead.

There's a better way to do this, however. Instead of manually keeping track of the last element in the list, you can just use [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add a new element onto the end.

```
var object_number = [];

function create_new_object()
{
    object_number.push(new happy_object());
}
```

When you want to find out how many elements are in the array, use [`Array.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) (or the number returned by `Array.push()`).

**Further reference:** [Array @ MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Answer (score 1):

your object_number is an empty array with no elements. Hence you are getting this error.
To add elements to array, you need to use push method.

```
object_number.push(new happy_object() );
```

Also you need to start your  array index from 0 instead of 1. i.e. your `x` should be 0.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers:

Unlike "normal" languages (which use block-scope), javascript uses function-scope.
So be shure x exists in side your function-scope when you use it like that.

Answer (score 0):

you can't mess with array keys too too much in js - if you want a more solid, definable relationship, you'll need to mimic an associative array by doing:

```
var object_number = {};
var x = 1;

function create_new_object() {
    object_number[x] = new happy_object();
}
```

Also, I'd combine your var statements. Makes variable/function hoisting a bit clearer.

```
var object_number = {}
  , x = 1;
```